# My Text View1 is visible in design but not in emulator or app while Text View2 is visible

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout

Text View2 is visible while Text View1 isn't visible. How to resolve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as image

Comment: Please add the xml code in your question, the image doesn't show the real issue.

Comment: You can layout_below="@id" to "@+". :)

Answer (score 0):

There aren't enough information in the picture you posted But I guess TextView1 might cover TextView2 . In that case you may change the positions or add a function which change one's visibility to "invisible" while another is visible.

Comment: No Text View1 is not covering Text View2; they both are individual part no one's dependent upon each other TextView1 is displaying Name while TextView2 is displaying email.id

Answer (score 0):

@Atul Awasthi, replace `android:layout_height="200dp"` for the RelativeLayout with
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:minHeight="200dp"` and that will fix your problem.